# html helper takes a dictionary<string,object>, how to use this parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

If a html helper takes a idictionary as a parameter, how do I use it?

I tried:

```
<%= Html.Blah( new { id = "blah" }) %>
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<%= Html.Blah( new Dictionary<string, object>(){
                                                   { "key", "value" },
                                                   { "key1", someObj },
                                                   { "blah", 1 }
                                               } );
```

Answer (score 7):

Just in case others run into this question too. There exists a helper method that will convert an anonymous object into a dictionary.

For example:

```
HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes( new { ng_model = "vm" } );
```

In other words, you can create your HTML helper method as per the OP's question to take an object and use this helper method inside. E.g.

```
public static string Blah(this HtmlHelper html, object htmlAttributes)
{
    // Create a dictionary from the object
    HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes( htmlAttributes );

    // ... rest of implementation
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The built-in HtmlHelper extension methods typically provide overloads that take an `object` parameter instead of `IDictionary<string, object>` in order to allow you to call them using an anonymous type as you tried.

If this is your own method, you could create another extension method that looks something like this:

```
    public static string Blah(this HtmlHelper html, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return html.Blah(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
```

The RouteValueDictionary's constructor takes an object and populates itself using the public properties of the object passed in.  I believe this is typically what the built-in HtmlHelper extension methods do as well.

Alternatively, you could call the method like this:

```
        html.Blah(new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "blah" }));
```

I haven't looked, but it seems obvious that the RouteValueDictionary class is doing some reflection in order to be able to identify the properties of the object.  Just be aware, in case that is something you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Generic Dictionary, Hashtable implements IDictionary as well.

```
 Html.Blah(new Hashtable(){
                        {"id", "blah"}
                    });
```